# DateTime in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

I am trying to order the final result of a select query using by order by "end_date" where "end_date" is of date datatype. Now I want to display the "end_date"in timestamp, so I have used :

```
to_char(end_date,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

Now in order to order by "end_date" I have to convert it to a date/datetime format since if I don't then it will consider it as a char datatype.Hence I do:

```
to_timestamp(to_char(end_date,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

But I have a .000000 milliseconds component at the end of the final "end_date" values. I am trying to remove this using other options like 'to_date' which infact removes the whole time component. Is their a way by which my following conditions can be satisfied:
1. The final results of 'end_date' should be ordered datetime.
2. The final results should not have a milliseconds component.Only the datetime component till minutes.

Comment: I'm confused. I get that you need the `to_char()` function to format `end_date` for display purposes.  But why do you need to perform any conversion to perform the `order by`?  Can't you just order by `end_date` directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `date` always has a day and a time component.  It appears that you merely want to `order by` the date and then display the `date` as a string in a particular format.  That would just be

```
SELECT to_char( my_date, <<whatever format you want>> )
  FROM my_table
 ORDER BY my_date
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried the same.But I try to "order by" it, it orders it considering it as a varchar. e.g:
It arranges data as:
12-Aug-2015
14-Jul-2014
16-Sep-2015
Ordering it ascending on the basis of First charaters that is only day.

Comment: @ghostrider - If `my_date` is a `date`, `order by my_date` will sort the results using date semantics not character string semantics.  If you are seeing results ordered by the string representation, you're either sorting on a string `order by to_char(...)` or `my_date` is not really a `date` it's a `varchar2` that represents a date.